# after using capdetection tool application stopped opening

Tags: windows-phone-7

i used capdetection tool for generating capabilities of of my wp7 app. when i pasted the capabilities generated by the tool, application build was successful but after installing in device application was not opening, after that i reverted back the previously present capabilities in manifest file and then app was launching fine. Is there any problem with capdetection tool. Can some one tell me the problem about the tool, Is that a certification requirement using capdetection tool for declaring capabilities in manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool exists so you can test your app with the capabilities it will be given when available through the marketplace. If you ignore the situation you have described you could end up failing marketplace certification or end up with an app that is unusable.

You are likely relying on a capability that the tool can't detect through static analysis.

I woudl strongly recommend you work out what this capability is and use it in a way that the tool can detect.

Comment: i am using one other project as my base project, do i need to give my bin/release path or bin/release/myapp.dll in capdetection tool, i tried with bin/release and it generated the required capabilities is that the correct approach??, becasue i think using bin/release/myapp.dll, tool was not able to detect capabilities of base project.

Answer (score 0):

You do no need to run the tool for certification, they run it during submission and replace the contents of the file regardless of what you put in there.

I believe the main purpose of it is so you can know in advance what services are going to be requested, giving you a chance to check they are correct.
For example some ad controls include location tracking and if you unexpectedly get that capability added on submission, you will probably fail as you need to ask the user and show privacy statements to have that capability.

Comment: thanks for your ans, i have one more doubt is that certification requirement is same as push notification, as for push notifications we we need to ask user first time when he install the app, if user wants notification for the app or not?

Comment: For push notifications you need to ask the user before enabling them and give them a place to turn them back off. See section 2.9.1 of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841(v=VS.92).aspx